# How to do trigger that implements this condition?

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I need trigger that implements this process:

I should +add some number 50 to that user to table `money` where in table `paym` both columns `table1` and `table2` are not empty.

For example: User `'John'` has both columns not empty and to him added `50` in table `money`.

**Example in table below:**

**table: `paym`**

```
 ID        username        table1        Table2  
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|   1   |  John       |  Value      |    Value  |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|   2   |  Alex       |  Null       |    Null   |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

**Table: `money`**

```
 ID      username      total_money      
+-------+-------------+-------------+
|   1   |  John       |     50      | 
+-------+-------------+-------------+
|   2   |  Alex       |     0       |
+-------+-------------+-------------+
```

**Query** for this: *(Not sure correct or not)*

```
UPDATE 
 money
SET 
 money.total_money = money.total_money + 50
INNER JOIN 
 paym
ON
 money.username = paym.username
WHERE
   (paym.Table1 IS NOT NULL OR paym.Table1 <> '')
 AND
   (paym.Table2 IS NOT NULL OR paym.Table2 <> '')
```

Comment: You don't need a trigger for this. You do need to use `AND` instead of `OR` in your conditions, and you need to fix the syntax of your UPDATE. But the join before the `SET` clause.

Comment: @Bill Karwin Thanks for your reply! But It should +add 50 for **every time** when new values inserted to `paym` for **every row** where condition  true!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a trigger for that purpose:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE trigger update_money_after_paym
AFTER INSERT ON paym
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.table1 IS NOT NULL AND NEW.table2 IS NOT NULL) THEN
        UPDATE money SET total_money = total_money + 50 WHERE username = NEW.username;
    END IF;
END;
$$
DELIMITER;
```

The code will run after each insert on table `paym`. If the newly inserted record has both columns `table1` and `table2` set to non-`NULL` values, then the trigger runs an `UPDATE` query that adds 50 to column `total_money` in table `money` for the record that has the same `username` as the newly inserted record in `paym`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! @GMB But Did you checked your trigger above? somehow syntax error occurs! When I'm trying to run!

Comment: @ShukurJank: just added a missing semi-column at the end of the `UPDATE` statement. If you are still getting errors, please let me know the error message.