# Trigger "AFTER INSERT" doesn't work, after insertion if I Add values in tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

**Purpose of trigger:**

I should +add some number 50 to that user to table `money` where in table `paym` both columns `table1` and `table2` are not empty.

For example: User `'John'` has both columns not empty and to him added `50` in table `money`.

**Example in table below:**

**table: `paym`**

```
 ID        username        table1        Table2  
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|   1   |  John       |  Value      |    Value  |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|   2   |  Alex       |  Null       |    Null   |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

**Table: `money`**

```
 ID      username      total_money      
+-------+-------------+-------------+
|   1   |  John       |     50      | 
+-------+-------------+-------------+
|   2   |  Alex       |     0       |
+-------+-------------+-------------+
```

Trigger below, works perfectly only when we insert all tables at one time. But it doesn't work if you insert only `username` two tables empty and after insertion, if you add values to **empty** tables `table1` and `table2` triggers not works at this point! Can we solve this problem???
*Trigger should work even if we add value to the table After insertion!*

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE trigger update_money_after_paym
AFTER INSERT ON paym
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.table1 IS NOT NULL AND NEW.table2 IS NOT NULL) THEN
        UPDATE money SET total_money = total_money + 50 WHERE username = NEW.username;
    END IF;
END;
$$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: Is this some homework and these two are classmates of yours? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55560450/how-to-do-trigger-that-implements-this-condition , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55559015/how-to-add-some-value-if-table-in-database-not-empty

Comment: @stickybit No bro These are my accounts! :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that trigger.  It is an `insert` trigger, so it doesn't get called for an `update`.

If you want an `update` trigger, then define one:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE trigger update_money_after_paym
AFTER UPDATE ON paym
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.table1 IS NOT NULL AND NEW.table2 IS NOT NULL) THEN
        UPDATE money m
            SET total_money = total_money + 50
            WHERE m.username = NEW.username;
    END IF;
END;
$$
DELIMITER;
```

This may not do exactly what you want.  For instance, you might only want to add `50` when the previous values are both `NULL`:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE trigger update_money_after_paym
AFTER UPDATE ON paym
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.table1 IS NOT NULL AND NEW.table2 IS NOT NULL AND
        OLD.table1 IS NULL AND old.table2 IS NULL) THEN
        UPDATE money m
            SET total_money = total_money + 50
            WHERE m.username = NEW.username;
    END IF;
END;
$$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: Thanks, Dude!!! Works perfectly! Really appreciate you!!! I just changed to `UPDATE`!